# How to enable gradle syntax highligting in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I installed STS plugin which include a Gradle IDE, but it seems not helping much.

[image]

### ADD 1

The effect with `Buildship Gradle Integration`'s `Gradle Build Script Editor`:

[image]

Comment: Eclipse buildship now has this in version 2.2.0+, use an update site as instructed on their github. https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/blob/master/docs/user/Installation.md#installing-from-eclipseorg-update-site

Answer (score 10):

I use Groovy editor from Groovy-Eclipse plugin to edit Gradle files. Since Gradle is basically Groovy it works very well. The plugin is available in the Eclipse Marketplace and [GitHub](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki#releases).

Buildship does not support source highlighting and probably never will due to planned transition from Groovy to Kotlin.

There is the following post in their forum: "[this is planned to be supported by Buildship at some point in the future. But, we do not have this on our immediate road map](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-build-script-editor/12079/3)".

Comment: You should installed it not from the Marketplace, but from the update website: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki#releases

Answer (score 5):

Use EGradle editor plugin - supports Syntax highlighting, code completion, error handling, and tool tip.

Install this plugin from market place:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egradle-editor

Comment: it is great. it supports code completion excellently

Comment: right click build.gradle -> Open With -> EGradle Editor

Answer (score 2):

Try installing this as an alternative: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nodeclipseenide-gradle-eclipse

It's for highlighting the gradle build file text. It's different from Groovy Eclipse plugin highlighting

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if buildship does not plan to provide better editor-support for groovy-gradle.

According to this (closed as wontfix) [buildship-bugzilla-bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=500335) the .gradle editor support is currently not planned.

> ### Quote from mentioned above bug
>
> [...]Actually, we have no plans for providing editor support for the
>   current Groovy DSL, because groovy-eclipse is essentially
>   unmaintained.
>
> We will provide integration with the Kotlin Eclipse plugin, since Kotlin will be the future preferred language for Gradle build scripts.[...]

Answer (score 1):

Editor from the Groovy-Eclipse plugin does not seem to be much of help for gradle scripts. I would recommend http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/minimalist-gradle-editor.

It is also not perfect, but still better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/blob/master/README.md), STS's Gradle tooling does not include an editor (it relies on the Groovy Eclipse plug-ins to provide the Groovy editor, Gradle is basically specialized Groovy).

The [Eclipse Buildship](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) project *does* include an editor. You can install it [via the Eclipse Marketplace.](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration)

Comment: I installed the `Buildship Gradle Integration`. I open the `build.gradle` with the `Gradle Build Script Editor`. But not much improved. See my screenshot.

Comment: Did you right-click the file and choose *Open with...* and then select the Gradle editor? The editor tab should have a green G icon.

Comment: Yes, I did that. Strange nothing changes.

Comment: The comment about the Groovy-Eclipse support is correct and there is still an slightly outdated version of that available, but that is no longer maintained. I would recommend to file this as an enhancement request against the Buildship project at Eclipse.